# Bought a Dyna-Glo 4800w 20 amp garage heater with 250v 6-30 factory plug end why ? Only has a 12AWG 6 ft cord ,which is commonly uses 20 amp breaker

Tags: hvac

Bought a Dyna-Glo 4800w 20 amp garage heater with 250v 6-30 amp factory cord plug end why ? If it's only a 12AWG 6 ft. Cord
12 AWG is normally on a 20 amp receptacle  so why the 240 6 -30 plug

Comment: Appliance cords are not to be put inside walls and packed in insulation.  They are regulated by UL regs, not NEC, which account for this difference.

Answer (score 4):

Check the manual and/or the nameplate specs to be sure of the details and to be sure it is properly listed (e.g., UL or ETL). But assuming everything is proper:

- 4800W = 240V x 20A. But the breaker and feed wire (in your walls) needs to be upsized 25% for continuous use = 25A. The next standard breaker size is 30A, so **30A** receptacle **and** breaker are required.
- The cord is only required to be sized to meet listing (e.g., UL or ETL) standards. Those are not always the same as the building electrical code (NEC). In particular, for a 30A circuit, 10 AWG minimum is required for electrical wiring *inside the walls*, but a cord that is sitting out, and therefore has air circulation to help remove heat, can often be a smaller size, such as the 12 AWG here, is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks, was going to run a 10 /2 wire anyways  was just wondering if  I  put  a 30 amp breaker  if it would trip it the 12 g cord got to warm ..was going to put in a 20 amp  and try it and see it it would trip the 20 amp breaker.  .would it of  damage the heater  or breaker  if I had of done that ?

Comment: Thanks I was going to use 10/2 wire surface mounted along  post and beams  not inside walls so air will get to the wire.

Comment: 10/2 with 30A is correct. 10/2 with 20A would likely work but runs the risk of nuisance trips if the heater runs for a long time. Breaker just measures current, so it wouldn't "know" if the wire overheated - that's why the rules are so strict. But my hunch is the 12  in the cord is counting (reasonably so) on air circulation taking care of the heat.

Comment: As far as your own wiring from receptacle to breaker: **You** can't rely on air circulation, etc. You have to play by the rules. There are a bunch of reasons, such as: "What if the next owner decides to cover up the wires". The cords on equipment play by different rules, which are regulated **and tested** by UL/ETL/etc. to make sure that things are safe.